# Retrieve data from server in single (one) page application - best practices

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, request, single-page-application

what's best practice for requesting/sending data from/to server in SPA (Angular, Ember)?

1. Make one request, get everything we need in our SPA

   - In nested hash (per resource/object)
   - Exactly structured just for the one specific request
2. Make multiple request per resource/object.

Every answer is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get everything I need in just ONE api call, as soon as possible - reducing round trips to server, connection usage in mobile devices.

Comment: And do you have it in structure per object (in nested json) or everything is just for the current request from SPA?

Comment: All entities from my backend is pulled on a single nested json